# conda install spyder=5.3.3 stuck on solving env

Tags: python, anaconda

I couldn't find much help on the internet, which is why I'm asking this here.

Spyder has an issue where `input()` will cause an issue to the app. I've heard that spyder 5.3.3 has this issue fixed.

I have done:

```
conda update conda
conda update anaconda
```

However, when I try `conda install spyder=5.3.3`, it says `failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.`

It then never solves the environment. Any help?

Answer (score 10):

I tried all the solution posted but they does not work for my problem. I finally solved it by first uninstalling the existing spyder version and installing a new one. To do this, use this:

```
conda uninstall spyder
conda install spyder = 5.3.3
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a great solution, ran into the same issue myself, I was able to install version 5.2.2 where 5.1.5 is the base version.  This version does also fix the input() problem you were having.

Alternatively you might try either of these two options to install spyder into it's own environment which should negate the problems but will require you to be in that environment to run spyder.

conda create -n spyder-env spyder
or
conda create -n spyder-env spyder numpy scipy pandas matplotlib sympy cython

Answer (score 0):

Me as well. At least you could get it updated to 5.2.2 using the recommended update command from anaconda's page for spyder:

```
conda install -c anaconda spyder
```

Or use Vaxion's solution by creating an environment.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I tried on many ways. But this last worked for me:

```
conda install -c anaconda spyder
```

Maybe you can try it too.

I took it from [anaconda / packages / spyder 5.3.3](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/spyder)

Answer (score 0):

Probably your Environment is broken somehow. I suggest you to create a new environment specifying `conda-forge` as a channel already at creation time:

```
conda create -n spyder-env -c conda-forge python=3.10 spyder=5.3.3
```

The newest versions of Spyder are usually available on this channel. Then you can install your other packages and libraries there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Like others, the upgrade was advancing very slowly. It was not urgent, so I just left it, and it took about a week (!) and ended by barfing out 7000+ lines of package conflicts.

But then I followed the advice from Qiyuan Chen and it worked in just a few minutes:

```
conda uninstall spyder
conda install spyder=5.3.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Qiyuan Chen's answer also worked for me. After I uninstalled and reinstalled it, I went back to Anaconda Navigator and the Spyder icon was there with an install button underneath it. I hit 'INSTALL' and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

As per others and Peters answer above

But then I followed the advice from Qiyuan Chen and it worked in just a few minutes:
Needed to turn the Anaconda Navigator off and on againbut I've now got Spyder 5.3.3 up and going with no distracting messages

Comment: This should be a comment on the answer you used to solve the issue, since this is not an answer by itself.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33478564)

Answer (score -1):

Close spyder. Run command: pip install --upgrade spyder

worked for me.

Comment: Note this warning (prompting on Spyder startup) might apply: "... Important note: Since you installed Spyder with Anaconda, please don't use pip to update it as that will break your installation. ..."

Comment: answers should address tool being used.  OP is posting about anaconda/miniconda error,  also pip has no knowledge of running w/in conda, so as others have pointed out this can cause issues.